Dynamically load partial HTML into element
I am currently learning HTML and I ran into a problem. Currently I have my navigation bar in my header.html page and I am trying to embed that into my main index.html, however it does not seem to be working.
This is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Certifications</a>
    <a href="#">Experience</a>
    <a href="#">Others</a>
    <div class="animation start-home"></div>
  </nav>
</header>
</html>

This is the main page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div w3-include-html="header.html"></div>

    <div class="background">
      <div>
        <div class="Page_Title">
          <h1>RITHVIK VADDADI</h1> 
        </div> 
        <div class="arrow-wrap">
          <div class="arrow-down arrow"></div>
          <div class="arrow-down arrow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="About">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <div class="ABT">
        <img src="Images/My PFP.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="Avatar">
        <p class="desciption">Hello, I am Rithvik Vaddadi, a current NSF with a diploma in Cyber Security and Digital Forensics. Drawn to the world of computers, I aspire to make people's lives easier and protect them from cyber attacks with the help of technology around us. As a problem solver, I am known to use my creative and critical thinking skills when providing solutions in my past leadership roles and projects. When involved in projects, I tend to notice people's strengths and weaknesses and assign them to roles where their potential would be fully maximized in the project. When my mind is fixed on a goal, I dedicate my energy and focus to achieving the goal.</p>
      </div>
      <h3>Looking</h3>
    </div>

  </body>
</html> 

This is the CSS code:
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin: 27px auto 0;
    width: 590px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

nav a{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav .animation{
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: darkred;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

a:nth-child(1){
    width: 100px;
}

nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
}

a:nth-child(2){
    width: 100px;
}

nav .start-projects,a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

a:nth-child(3){
    width: 150px;
}

nav .start-certifications,a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation{
    width: 150px;
    left: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(4){
    width: 100px;
}

nav .start-others,a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 350px;
}

a:nth-child(5){
    width: 100px;
}

nav .start-others,a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 450px;
}

.background{
    background-image: url(Images/CardistryBGD2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: -8px; 
}

.Page_Title{
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.arrow-wrap {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: arrow 0.5s 1s infinite ease-out alternate;
    -moz-animation: arrow 0.5s 1s infinite ease-out alternate;
    -o-animation: arrow 0.5s 1s infinite ease-out alternate;
    animation: arrow 0.5s 1s infinite ease-out alternate;
    width: 56px;
    margin-left: 600px;
}
  
.arrow-wrap:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
  
.arrow {
    padding: 15px;
    border-left: solid 5px red;
    border-bottom: solid 5px whitesmoke;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
  
.arrow-down {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom:200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: relative;
}
  
@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
    0% {
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      bottom: 10px;
    }
}
  
@-moz-keyframes arrow {
    0% {
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      bottom: 10px;
    }
}
  
@keyframes arrow {
    0% {
      bottom: -100px;
    }
    100% {
      bottom: -90px;
    }
}

h1{
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9vw;
    color: white;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 30px;
}

.Avatar{
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 145px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

.About{
    margin: -9px;
    background-image: url(Images/CardBG.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;

}

.ABT{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1150px;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.desciption{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

Initially, everything was on index.html, until I separated the navigation bar into a separate html page, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

w3-include-html needs the script from w3schools, a resource I would not recommend. ESPECIALLY not when it comes to Cyber Security - the include they use uses innerHTML, which is sensitive to XSS

In order to dynamically include a HTML partial, you could place this JavaScript inside a page right before the closing </body> tag:
index.html
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("[data-include]").forEach(async (el) => {
  try {
    const [file, selector] = el.dataset.include.split(/ +/);
    const res = await fetch(file);
    const html = await res.text();
    const domp = new DOMParser();
    const doc = domp.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    el.append(selector ? doc.querySelector(selector) : doc.documentElement);
  } catch (err) { console.error(err) };
});
</script>
<!-- </body> goes here! -->

Then, you can use that script like:
<div data-include="header.html"></div>

header.html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
  </nav>
</header>

or by a specific ID selector:
<div data-include="header.html #header"></div>

header.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav >
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
            <a href="#">Other</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- other partials with ID -->
</body>
</html>

Keep in mind that it's always best to Server Side Render your pages in their entirety in order to prevent flash-of-content or even missing/broken partials.

I assume you use the clunky domparser approach to make the script XSS resilient? I applaud that approach since Ritvik seems to be interested in Cyber Security

@mplungjan I'm not sure to capture the essence of your comment :) If you fetch files from a trusted resource (your own) I can't see how XSS would pose an issue. Also, not sure why you wrote: "Ritvik seems to be interested in Cyber Security" ? Could you expand? PS, yes, the DOMParser could be used i.e: inside an if (selector) { and otherwise inject directly using innerHTML = html; but that would nest the  <html> in an existing <html> if the header.html wraps into one...

Hello, I am Rithvik Vaddadi, a current NSF with a diploma in Cyber Security And my first comment was "If you fetch it from trusted source, then just do a fetch with innerHTML, but then I realised that your DOMParser actually will be safer and changed my comment. Of course the partial HTML had to not be wrapped in 

@mplungjan eagle eyes :) Had to use Ctrl+F to realize ;)

You forgot to include the script w3.js
Add this script to index.html:
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

That could be a comment and a vote to close as typo-type

@mplungjan why? There is this line: <div w3-include-html="header.html"></div>. Including the script will make the entire page work, as precise OP request

@mplungjan the tag [w3.js] clearly points in this direction. I see your security concerns, but I think it's a whole different story

Yes. OP forgot to include the most important line. The question and this answer is not useful to anyone else but OP. I already commented the fact so they could have deleted the question. The only useful part of this is the answer by Roko, since it actually shows a better approach than the poor code from w3schools

The tagging makes it even more "Cannot reproduce if you do what you are supposed to do"
